# UV-Vis Spectrum, using readline() method

Tags: python, readline, spectrum

So I have been set this work to list data that is provided as a data file called "Spectrum.dat". If the code is correct, when you run the cell in Jupyter, below you should see the list of energies [2.1674, 2.1724, 2.1774, 2.1824, etc...] and the list of intensities [6.4e-07, 1.26e-06, 2.39e-06, 4.36e-06, etc...].

```
spect = ___

eV = []
inten = [] 

for line in spect.readlines():
    if not (">" in ___):
        tmp = line___ 
        eV.append(float(tmp[0]))
        inten.append(float(tmp[1]))

print(eV)
print(inten)
```

I'm trying to find out what the underscores are. The first bit I added was `spect = open("spectrum.dat", "r+")` and I am assuming the second underscores is `if not (">" in spect):` so now i am stuck on the last one.

Below is the Spectrum.dat file:

[image: "Spectrum.dat" file]

Comment: Your second line ____ assumption is wrong, look at the loop it's in. The third ____ could be a number of things, but it's hard to tell because we don't know what the format of the file you're opening is - tab separated, spaces, or whatever else might be in there?

Comment: @Andrew the format of the file is a .dat file.

Comment: Sorry, when I mentioned the format, I meant specifically what is separating the two values in each line in the file you're describing? think about how you might separate a string based on knowing what separates

Comment: @Andrew Got it to work thanks. I changed the second to list and third was line.split.